# How to add a dynamic CrudController on a field Symfony/Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

***Situation:***

I use EasyAdmin for the backend. I have an entity named **Vehicle**. From it, I've created **Car** and **Bicycle**.

I have another entity with a OneToMany relation linked to **Vehicle**. Problem is, when I click the link created by EasyAdmin, it redirects me to the admin page with the **Vehicle** crudId. I need it to redirect me to either to the **Car** or the **Bicycle** one, depending on the type of the **Vehicle**.

I've set the AssociationField like this:

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
{
    return [
        AssociationField::new('Vehicle', 'The vehicle')->autocomplete()->setCrudController(Car::class)
    ]
}
```

***Problem:***

You can see that I set the crud controller to Car, but here is my problem : I need to set this dynamically, either Car or Bicycle. Is it possible to do it?

Thank you to everyone helping :)

Answer (score 0):

So, you can create listener for `controller` event, and choose the right one and pass it like here https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-controller

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ControllerEvent;

public function onKernelController(ControllerEvent $event)
{
    // ...

    // the controller can be changed to any PHP callable
    $event->setController($myCustomController);
}
```